# How large should the number of features be to start using batch gradient descent versus normal equations

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, gradient-descent

Suppose you want to train a multivariate linear regression on an n x m dataset. Also suppose n > m. The runtime of determining your parameter

```
theta = (theta0, theta1, ..., thetam)
```

using the normal equations is

```
~ O(m^2 * n),
```

as calculating

```
(X^t) * X is in O(m^2 * n).
```

Gradient descent has a runtime of

```
O(n * m) * the_number_of_iterations,
```

where the number_of_iterations is usually about 1000 or so (from what i've seen). So am I right in thinking that I should be using gradient descent whenever

```
m ^ 2 * n > n * m * the_number_of_iterations
m > the_number_of_iterations
m >~ 1000 or so
```

if all i care about is speed? Is this too simplistic of a rule or are there other considerations I should be taking into account? How do other people decide which algorithm to use? Thanks for the help.